# mean squared error in scikit learn RidgeCV

Tags: scikit-learn, mse, mean-square-error

My question is: In `sklearn`, how is the `cv_values_` given by `RidgeCV` calculated? why is it different with output from `metrics.mean_squared_error`?

For example,

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array([1,3.5,4,4.9,6.1,7.2,8.1,8.9,10,11.1])
ax.plot(X, y, 'o')
ax.plot(X, X+1, '-') # help visualize
```

[image]

Say we train the Ridge model on X and y

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
model = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.001], store_cv_values=True).fit(X, y)
```

Now the output of

```
mean_squared_error(y_true=y, y_pred=model.predict(X))
```

is `0.1204000013110009`, while the output of

```
model.cv_values_.mean()
```

is `0.24472577167818438`.

Why is there such a huge difference? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Let me know if the answer solved your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official website [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html)

**cv_values_**

Cross-validation values **for each alpha** (*if store_cv_values=True and cv=None*). After fit() has been called, this attribute will contain **the mean squared errors (by default)** or the values of the {loss,score}_func function (if provided in the constructor).

In your case when you call the

`model = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.001], store_cv_values=True).fit(X, y)`

you have: `cv=None`

`cv=None` means that you use the Leave-One-Out cross-validation.

So `cv_values` stores the mean squared error for each sample using Leave-One out cross validation. In every fold you have only 1 test point and thus n = 1. So `cv_values_` will give you the squared error for every point in your training data set when it was a part of the test fold.

Finally, this means that when you call `model.cv_values_.mean()`, you get the mean of these individual errors (mean of each error for each point). To see these individual error you can use `print(model.cv_values_)`

Individual means that the n=1 in the following equation:

[image]

On the other hand, `mean_squared_error(y_true=y, y_pred=model.predict(X))` means that you put n=10 in this equation.

So the 2 results will differ.

Comment: Ah I see. I did read the documentation of RidgeCV, but I didn't take the number of points participated in the MSE calculation into consideration. Thx!

Comment: Glad that I could help